# Multiple files uploaded on server while doing ajax post but not being uploaded using XMLHttpRequest() post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Was doing **POST** operation using ajax() and XMLHttpRequest(). Ajax  from HTML form itself where as  XMLHttpRequest() was using javascript. Below is the code for both requests made.

**XMLHttpRequest() client side code:**

```
multiUpload(uploadFiles){                       
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        var uploadFormData = new FormData();
        var i=0;

        for(i=0; i < uploadFiles.length ; i++){          
                uploadFormData.append('uploadFiles', uploadFiles[i]);
            }

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   
                 xhr.open('post', MULTI_FILE_UPLOAD_URL , true);

            xhr.onload = function () {
              if (this.status == 200) {     
                    console.log("Resolve done !!!");            
                    resolve(this.response);
                 } else {
                        console.log("Reject done !!!");
                        reject(this.statusText);
                }
                };
                console.log(uploadFormData);    
                xhr.send(uploadFormData);
            });
        }
```

`uploadFiles` contains FileList object in the above code having multiple files objects.

**Client side code for making ajax call:**

```
<form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/photo" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple />
             <!-- Input form goes here -->
</form>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
                        $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
                            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                                error: function(xhr) {
                                    status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
                                },
                                success: function(response) {
                                            console.log(response)
                                $("#status").empty().text(response);
                            }
                            });
                        return false;
                });    
            });
        </script>
```

**Server side code for XMLHttpRequest() and ajax call:**

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
         destination: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, newPath);
            },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
                callback(null, file.originalname );
            }});

    var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto');

    app.post('/multiFileUpload', function(req, res) {

         upload(req,res,function(err){
                console.log(req);
          if(err){
                console.log("Error in upoading file "+err);
            return res.send("Server Error in uploading file.");
        }
                res.send("File is uploaded successfully.");
        });
```

Now, when I display the `req` object in the console from the server code, I am getting the following result [image] (Left is ajax call and right is XMLHttpRequest() call). I am actually uploading multiple file at a time in the server. With ajax call file is getting uploaded but with XMLHttpRequest() , this is not happening and an error is coming. How to achieve the same result with XMLHttpRequest() ? One more thing, the way app object is created in both the ways is:

**For XMLHttpRequest() -**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.Router();
```

**For Ajax call is: -**

```
var express =   require("express");
var app =   express();
```

So, is this creating an issue ?